# Validate request Body using github.com/jarcoal/httpmock

Tags: unit-testing, go

The function I am trying to test accepts data structs, forms a `query_dsl` and then makes a `/_search` call to elastic search with the formed query.
Hence I want to assert on the `query_dsl` and `url` which gets formed.

I am using `github.com/jarcoal/httpmock` to mock `net/http` requests in my unit tests. As per the doc it exposes `func GetCallCountInfo() map[string]int` to validate how many times a particular endpoint was hit.
But I am also interested in knowing what was the request body when this call was made.

`http.Client` is not exposed, hence can not override/mock that for testing.

If it is not possible using this package then is there any other library which can mock the network request and also gives hold of request body?

Comment: Just use the httptest server https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#example_Server and don't try to mock this in Go. There you can manipulate all the data you want.

Comment: this creates a new mock http server. It does not capture the request made to other servers. So it wont solve the purpose in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @georgeok Suggestion,
We can create a mock [http server](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptest/#NewServer) and capture the request body when request is made.
Following is the code snippet to create a server and store the request body.

```
server := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        actualRequestBody, err = ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
        check(err)
        // Send mock response to be tested
        _, err := rw.Write(bytes)
        check(err)
    }))

    defer server.Close()
```

Now our request body is stored on `actualRequestBody` variable, and we can assert on this for correctness.

The only thing necessary to make sure this works is to make the call at host `server.URL`. As it spins up a server on the address mentioned at `server.URL`. So if the call from your code is being made to different server this will not catch it.